# I can't see my 'Live' skill on Skills Website, but it's visible in the Alexa App

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I can see my skill on my Alexa App as shown in the screenshot.[image: Screenshot of my skill in Alexa App]

But when I search for it on the Amazon Alexa Skills site, It is not listed there among all the skills. 
Also, it is not listed under "Your Skills" tab on the website.

Why is it so? and what is the solution for it?

Comment: Did you submit it for certification? Was it certified?

Comment: Yes, it was submitted, reviewed & is made 'Live' by them.

I **can** see it in my Alexa app, even under **All Skills**, but if I open up Alexa Skills on Amazon.com & search for the same, It doesnt show up.

Is it because of Language settings? I have it published under **en-IN**

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so as it stands, Amazon takes some time to make it available on the skills store.
After contacting Support, my issue was resolved.

Comment: Still stuck in this situation in 2020.. How long did it take for your skill to appear in the store? Mine was published 2 days ago and still is not indexed.

Answer (score 0):

- First, go to [Alexa Web App](https://alexa.amazon.com) on your laptop.
- Second, Click the tab
  Skills on left drop-down menu.
- Last, look to the top right, you will
  see Your Skills => there you go.

Comment: I can see it there. I think you haven't read the question.
I can't see it on **amazon.com/alexa-skills** site where all Alexa Skills are listed.